# Why does $\int_{\Omega}\Delta u \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d }{d t}|u|^2_{H^1_0}$ hold?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, laplacian

In [his book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387948669), Roger Temam, considered the following reaction diffusion system:[image]
He considered the norms:
[image]

What I don't get is what's written here
[image]
How does he obtain the equality:
[image]

It seems that to have this equality using Green, we should have $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$ on the boundary of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$ on $\partial\Omega$, since (see eq. (1.3))
$$\forall x\in \partial\Omega, \forall t\in\mathbb{R}^+\ \ u(x,t)=0.$$
Therefore in these $x$, $u$ is independent of $t$ and the partial derivative satisfies
$$\forall x\in \partial \Omega,\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,\cdot)=0.$$